# Subpixel color in flash/actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript, fonts, subpixel

When working with text in Flash, I often encounter the following problem:

http://www.aino.se/media/i/subpixel.png

This makes the text "glow" in various colors. Is there any good way to avoid this? It has something to do with subpixel rendering, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried most of the options available.

Comment: Do you have an example we could use to verify your problem? Just the TextFormat and TextField settings you used for this example would be enough.

Comment: generally it has to do with your anti-alias settings on that textfield. Usually it means you're sharpness setting is too high for the font you're using.

Comment: Try making it sure that all your sprite/display object positions are integers? But not sure if that might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit print screen on this website if you are on PC win7 and paste it to photoshop. Zoom in and then you'll see this is the way how subpixel anti-aliasing became a standard method these days. Turn this off and everything looks ugly. Is not what Win XP or OSX was about. The old school anti-aliasing was based on grey scale. Sub pixel is using full palette of colors. Not mention that this patent belongs to Microsoft only.

This invention improved text quality on LCD a lot but we loosing a pixel perfection in other hand. And Flash performing under Win 7 (I wonder if Vista as well) using native method. If you want to avoid this effect draw Text Field on BitmapData, select BitmapText or use pixel font. By the way if you are on XP and full screen mode you can experience similar effect